# Export UnityProject inside Android Studio's existing project

Tags: unity, c#, android, android-studio, jni

I am new to the Unity3D, but I have made a small Unity project with a humanoid `gameobject`. I can move this humanoid with the demo data but I want to move it with the quaternion data which I am already getting inside the android app.

I have searched on the internet, but everyone just tells about the android plugin that we have to make for the unity, and that way we can use the JNI to send or receive the data (I need to access the c# scripts from the android).

But, I wanted to import the unity project inside the android project so that I can(access the c# scripts from android and send the quaternion data to the Quaternion variable of the `gameObject` and make it move) make changes to the android app and test it instantly!! (Also I don't need to make further changes inside the unity project but I need to make further improvements to the data inside the android project).

Please help and provide a guide for the android studio.
Thanks.

Comment: The advice you found about using a plugin to communicate with Unity was good advice.

Comment: okay.. but if i use that approach.. it will take me quite a bit of time to make any kind of change in android app and test it....

Comment: What you should do in this instance, is create a DLL for your android communications, which would be your Unity Plugin for this data.  If you need to make changes, you build a new DLL and replace it inside of the Unity plugins folder.  So if you need to make a change, yeah, you would have to do it from Android Studio -- create a new build -- and update the linked DLL .

Comment: Yup, working with Unity and any direct connections with Android is a hassle.

Comment: Ohh..thanks @Jon, but what is the difference between using a .dll and using a jar(according to the docs) here..?

Comment: @Almo, yeah i have heard that before..:P

Comment: @Jon, can you please tell me the difference here...Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is essentially the same thing. I should have said Jar not Dll.

Comment: Ohh..no problem.!!